# Multisite Image file path function?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, image-uploading, image-upload

In a multisite environment, if a user uploads an image it is being put in the wrong place and is thus not found `http://www.example.com/suppliers/files//home/root/public_html//files/job-manager-uploads/featured_image/2016/03/example-image.jpg`

I need to write a function or htaccess redirect or something to change this upload path to be `http://www.example.com/suppliers/files/2016/03/example-image.jpg`

Any ideas please?!

```
function job_manager_upload_dir( $pathdata ) {
    global $job_manager_upload, $job_manager_uploading_file;

    if ( ! empty( $job_manager_upload ) ) {
        $dir = apply_filters( 'job_manager_upload_dir', 'job-manager-uploads/' . sanitize_key( $job_manager_uploading_file ), sanitize_key( $job_manager_uploading_file ) );

        if ( empty( $pathdata['subdir'] ) ) {
            $pathdata['path']   = $pathdata['path'] . '/' . $dir;
            $pathdata['url']    = $pathdata['url'] . '/' . $dir;
            $pathdata['subdir'] = '/' . $dir;
        } else {
            $new_subdir         = '/' . $dir . $pathdata['subdir'];
            $pathdata['path']   = str_replace( $pathdata['subdir'], $new_subdir, $pathdata['path'] );
            $pathdata['url']    = str_replace( $pathdata['subdir'], $new_subdir, $pathdata['url'] );
            $pathdata['subdir'] = str_replace( $pathdata['subdir'], $new_subdir, $pathdata['subdir'] );
        }
    }

    return $pathdata;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'job_manager_upload_dir' );
```

Comment: Show your code , how are you getting path for upload.

Comment: @DeepKakkar I think it is being generated the plugin WP Job Manager via the plugins functions.php

Comment: It all worked ok when I was using development site however when I moved it onto a sub site (multi site) it now doesnt work

Comment: better if you put code in question.

Comment: Its the backend code, Show me the front end code where you are diplaying image, in `img` tag.

Comment: The front end code is irrelevant